# How to prevent Nokogiri from adding <DOCTYPE> tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I noticed something strange using Nokogiri recently. All of the HTML I had been parsing had been given start and end `<html>` and `<body>` tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body>\n
```

How can I prevent Nokogiri from doing this?

I.E., when I do:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<div>some content</div>")
doc.to_s
```

or:

```
doc.to_html
```

I get the original:

```
<html blah><body>div>some content</div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 92):

The problem occurs because you're using the wrong method in Nokogiri to parse your content.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<p>foobar</p>')
puts doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body><p>foobar</p></body></html>
```

Rather than using `HTML` which results in a complete document, use `HTML.fragment`, which tells Nokogiri you only want the fragment parsed:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment('<p>foobar</p>')
puts doc.to_html
# >> <p>foobar</p>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Disregard the answer below. Can you select your own answer as the correct answer? That's just weird.

Comment: Just for the record, the answer to which rainkinz is referring that should be disregarded has been deleted :)

Answer (score 6):

The `to_s` method on a `Nokogiri::HTML::Document` outputs a valid HTML page, complete with its required elements. This is not necessarily what was passed in to the parser.

If you want to output less than a complete document, you use methods such as `inner_html`, `inner_text`, etc., on a node.

Edit: if you are not expecting to parse a complete, well-formed XML document as input, then theTinMan's answer is best.

Comment: doc.inner_html.to_s seems to work.