# Delete regex phrase from text

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a text with news where i got html attributes that i don't need. How can i delete phrases in ruby such as

> img width="750" alt="4.jg" c="/unload/medialiy/df6/4.jg" height="499"
> title=4.jg"
>
> img width="770" alt="5.jg" c="/unload/medialiy/ty6/5.jg"
> height="499" title=5.jg"

So i need some regex smth like `news.sub('/img*jg"/, '')`. but it doesn't work.

Comment: _"a text with news where i got html attributes"_ – what does that mean? Do you have HTML or text containing HTML? Why are the angle brackets  missing? How does your actual input look like (i.e. `news`) and what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
img .*\.jg"
```

[test](https://regex101.com/)

if you want to say in regex "any symbols in any quantity", use `.*` Dot means any symbol, and star - any quantity.

But are you sure you don't want to include angle braces?

```
<img .*\.jg">
```

As an aside, what if the order of attributes will be changed? Then you'll fail to match the img tag. We really need img tag with `.jg"` substring in it.

```
<img [^>]*\.jg"[^>]*>
```

[test](https://regex101.com/r/dVCGkF/1)

Comment: _"Dot means any symbol"_ – are you sure that you want `.jg` then? ;-)

Comment: Oh! How foolish of me to omit back slashes! Practically, it was a longer substitution for '.?'. It was a correct regex, so tests passed, but not good for explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case you can do this:

```
element = '<img width="750" alt="4.jg" c="/unload/medialiy/df6/4.jg" height="499" title="4.jg">'

puts element.gsub(/(width|alt)=\"[^ ]+\" ?/, '')
```

You can also play around with this regex [here](http://rubular.com/r/EsGi4TjWQn).

But if you need a more robust solution, try to take a look at the [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) gem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096327/strip-style-attributes-with-nokogiri) SO question can help.