# Stop Nokogiri from adding DOCTYPE and meta tags?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to use Nokogiri to convert some template files from one format to another. But it keeps adding tags. I'm trying to prevent it from adding Doctype and meta tags, but can't figure it out. I've tried

```
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(r)
```

but that adds the tags. I've also tried

```
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(r)
```

as suggested in "[How to prevent Nokogiri from adding <DOCTYPE> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723344/how-to-prevent-nokogiri-from-adding-doctype-tags)", but that removes any `<html>`, `<head>`, or `<body>` tags that are in the document.

If it matters, my code for reading the file is:

```
f = File.read(infile)
r = f.gsub(/<tmpl_var ([^>]*)>/, '{{{\1}}}')
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(r)
```

I need to do a `gsub` beforehand because I need to replace `<tmpl_var>` tags which aren't proper HTML and cause more problems.

When using `HTML.fragment(r)`, I do get an `htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <html> tag` error (as well as similar errors for `<body>` and `<head>`).

Is there a way to prevent it from making these additions?

An example conversion:

Before:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var x = "y";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            Stuff
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

After using Parse:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script>
            var x = "y";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            Stuff
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

After using `HTML.fragment` or `HTML::DocumentFragment.parse`:

```
<script>
    var x = "y";
</script>

<div>
    Stuff
</div>
```

In this case, I want it to just output the before section. (In the real script I make a bunch of changes though).

Comment: Nowhere in your "before" or "after" sections do you show the tag you're trying to replace. Instead, it looks like you're asking about two different problems.

Comment: Replacing the tags is a different problem, and one I've solved. Right now I'm just focused on stopping it from adding the doctype tags. The tmpl_var thing isn't relevant to this question, I just have it in there as a direct copy of how I read the file into Nokogiri, in case using a String instead of the File directly matters.

Comment: If the temple_var thing isn't relevant, then you shouldn't even document or mention it as it is a [red herring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

Comment: "I just have it in there as a direct copy of how I read the file into Nokogiri, in case using a String instead of the File directly matters." If you nose around in the [documentation for parsing](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/HTML/Document.html#method-c-parse), you'll see statements like "string_or_io may be a String, or any object that responds to read and close such as an IO, or StringIO."

Answer (score 3):

Nokogiri can be told to *not* add the standard HTML headers. Consider these:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<p>foo</p>')
doc.to_html # => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body><p>foo</p></body></html>\n"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment('<p>foo</p>')
doc.to_html # => "<p>foo</p>"
```

---

`tmpl_var` is a bad tag name in HTML, as is `{{{\1}}}`, so asking Nokogiri to try to parse either will result in problems:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment('<templ_var p1="baz">foo</templ_var>')
doc.errors # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Tag templ_var invalid>]
```

But you can still munge the DOM:

```
doc.to_html # => "<templ_var p1=\"baz\">foo</templ_var>"
doc.search('templ_var').each { |t| t.name = 'bar'}
doc.to_html # => "<bar p1=\"baz\">foo</bar>"
```

Or:

```
doc.to_html # => "<div><templ_var p1=\"baz\">foo</templ_var></div>"
doc.search('templ_var').each { |t| t.replace('{{{\1}}}') }
doc.to_html # => "<div>{{{\\1}}}</div>"
```

Putting that stuff together, plus a bit of chicanery:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment('<div><templ_var p1="baz">foo</templ_var></div>')

doc.to_html # => "<div><templ_var p1=\"baz\">foo</templ_var></div>"

doc.search('templ_var').each { |t| t.replace('{{{\1}}}') }
doc.to_html # => "<div>{{{\\1}}}</div>"

header = Nokogiri::XML.fragment('<html><body>')
header.at('body').children = doc
header.to_html # => "<html><body><div>{{{\\1}}}</div></body></html>"
```

So, I'd go after it something like that.

Now, *why* is Nokogiri stripping the `<html>` tag when parsing a fragment? I don't know. It leaves `<body>` alone if `<head>` or `<html>` is missing:

```
Nokogiri::HTML.fragment('<p>foo<p>').to_html 
# => "<p>foo</p><p></p>"
Nokogiri::HTML.fragment('<body><p>foo<p></body>').to_html 
# => "<body>\n<p>foo</p>\n<p></p>\n</body>"
```

But it gets funky if `<head>` or `<html>` exists:

```
Nokogiri::HTML.fragment('<head><style></style></head><body><p>foo<p></body>').to_html 
# => "<style></style><p>foo</p><p></p>"
Nokogiri::HTML.fragment('<html><head><style></style></head><body><p>foo<p></body></html>').to_html 
# => "<style></style><p>foo</p><p></p>"
```

That smells like a bug in Nokogiri to me as I haven't seen anything to document that behavior.

Comment: That does the same thing as just Html.fragment. If the HTML you feed it contains `<html>` tags, it will remove them.

Comment: Your edit still doesn't fix the issue. <tmpl_var> tags are removed with a gsub before I even get to Nokogiri anyways. They are not relevant. I need to replace a lot of tags, which I can do, and it needs to be recursive. Those tags aren't the problem, note that my Before/After examples don't include them. I need to know how to make Nokogiri not add new tags, while not removing head, html, and body tags already in the html.

Comment: I think you'll need to [take it to the Nokogiri authors](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) as it acts like a bug.

Comment: Doesn't look like it. The source code for parse seems to indicate it's supposed to ignore those tags. I found a solution though, using XML instead of HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can get around this by using `Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment` instead of `Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment`. The XML version won't remove the html, head, or body tags.